# Python aiohttp returns a different reponse than python requests. I need help understanding why

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping, aiohttp

after the whole evening yesterday and morning today i really an help for understanding why, aiohttp request returns differently than requests request.

```
import requests

reqUrl = "https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data"

headersList = {
 "Accept": "*/*",
 " User-Agent" : " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36" 
}

payload = ""

response = requests.request("GET", reqUrl, data=payload,  headers=headersList)

print(response.text)
```

returns whole content
{"collections":[{"symbol"....

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio 

headersList = {
            'authority': 'api-mainnet.magiceden.io',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'origin': 'https://magiceden.io',
            'referer': 'https://magiceden.io/',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
            'sec-gpc': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.61 Safari/537.36',
        }

payload = ""

async def test():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        get_image_data = await session.get(
                            'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data', headers=headersList)
        result = get_image_data.text

        print(result)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(test())
```

returns:

```
<bound method ClientResponse.text of <ClientResponse(https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data) [200 OK]>
<CIMultiDictProxy('Date': 'Thu, 02 Jun 2022 12:43:22 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-Powered-By': 'Express', 'X-RateLimit-Limit': '120', 'X-RateLimit-Remaining': '119', 'X-RateLimit-Reset': '1654173863', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://magiceden.io', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=300', 'CDN-Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=300', 'Etag': 'W/"4f27d7-Cndhwdfejd0aSIGFdSQriuQfbvE"', 'Set-Cookie': 'connect.sid=s%3AcUUsXzow-3-5kuLPJcNNndd5zVxtCIvc.ggQdFm%2FooB%2FpWho%2FqYiVWJQa4vCtQ9VZGRisUqFXigw; Domain=magiceden.io; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 02 Jun 2022 12:53:22 GMT; HttpOnly', 'X-Kong-Upstream-Latency': '242', 'X-Kong-Proxy-Latency': '0', 'Via': 'kong/2.7.2', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Set-Cookie': '__cf_bm=i5THtMhPjqGPXy8zFyXSP43DLHQESpOLbWff7n_W6qE-1654173802-0-AQkuHSP7Sv+YRRSr1wmUBDKb5EOjcAiPVXyx7lvqe0NF2wmLHcFK9JFLPVkiuTpMOjp/wpiMpQU377nAimriGP0=; path=/; expires=Thu, 02-Jun-22 13:13:22 GMT; domain=.magiceden.io; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '715046367a9b0219-ZRH', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400')>
>
```

can someone help me understanding why?
Thanks a lot guys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is actually in a `StreamReader` object in the `content` attribute

```
get_image_data = await session.get('https://api-mainnet.magiceden.io/all_collections_with_escrow_data', headers=headersList)
stream = get_image_data.content
data = await stream.read()
print(data)
```

Comment: Why this over the shorter `await get_image_data.text()`?

Answer (score 7):

The output you see is because `text` is supposed to be called as an (async) method, not looked up as an attribute.

If you just want the full response body as a string, you need to `await response.text()` as shown in the [official `aiohttp` tutorial](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request):

```py
async def test():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers_list) as response:
            text = await response.text()

    print(text)
```

One difference between `requests.get` and `aiohttp.ClientSession.get` is that `requests` fetches the whole body of the response at once and remembers it, but `aiohttp` doesn't. `aiohttp` lets you ignore the body, or read it in chunks, or read it after looking at the headers/status code.

That's why you need to do a second `await`: `aiohttp` needs to do more I/O to get the response body.